# What does "ach" stand for? In manifest file, in overview application of SAP

Tags: annotations, manifest, sap-web-ide

This is an extract from manifest.json file of my overview application.
created using annotations
https://blogs.sap.com/2016/01/29/steps-to-create-analytic-card-on-overview-page-using-northwind-odata-service-v3-in-web-ide/

```
"sap.app": {
        "id": "ovpdemo",
        "type": "application",
        "i18n": "i18n/i18n.properties",
        "applicationVersion": {
            "version": "1.2.2"
        },
        "title": "{{app_title}}",
        "description": "{{app_description}}",
        "ach": "sap",
```

Answer (score 1):

It refers to SAP Support component which you need to use while raising bugs to SAP.

Answer (score 1):

To be precise:

> **Application component hierarchy** (SAP's component names for bug
>   reports); attribute is mandatory for SAP apps, but is not used so far
>   for apps developed outside SAP

Cited from:
https://help.sap.com/viewer/0ce0b8c56fa74dd897fffda8407e8272/7.5.6/en-US/be0cf40f61184b358b5faedaec98b2da.html